# Что делает stringstream и не только?

Tags: char, строки, c++, классы

Что делает класс stringstream?

```
stringstream ss(input);    
while (ss >> input)
```

По логике программы, так понимаю, что я ввожу строку ss, после чего включается цикл и по одному слову оно начинает передавать из ss в input?

Вторая беда вот эта.

```
    if(input.front() == input.back())
    {

        size_t found = output.find(input);
        if (found == string::npos)
        {
            output.append(input);
            output.append(" ");
        }
    }
```

И так проверяет в слове, равны ли первый и последний символ. Дальше непонятно. Строка output пустая, как оно может в ней искать подстроку input? 
В общем, можно поподробней разъяснить, как тут все работает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `stringstream` — это такой же `stream`, как и, например, `cin`, только его содержимое берётся не из входного потока программы, а из данной ему строки. Эффект от вашего кода в принципе такой же, как от `while (cin >> input)`, если бы пользователь ввёл содержимое `input` вручную (но программа не останавливается в ожидании ввода). Заметьте, что переменная `input` используется дважды: один раз чтобы инициализировать `stringstream`, а потом в цикле читая куски этого самого `stringstream`. (Это не очень красиво, я бы не пожалел объявить для нового смысла новую переменную.)
2. Это вначале строка `output` пустая, а после первого раза в ней добавится текст. Попробуйте протрассировать программу для такой исходной строки: `"one one ne two two"`, вам сразу станет яснее.

Comment: Т.е. я ввожу "text text", начинается и заканчивается одним и тем же символом. if (found == string::npos) это условие в 1, когда в строке output нет подстроки input. Получается, первый раз в пустой строке нету text, поэтому оно зайдет в условие. А в следующий раз уже нет? Так?

Comment: @Janitor93: именно так.